# Batteries problem

Tags: batteries

I have a few Li-ion and NiCd cells of 3.7V of around 3300mAh and more but due to over charging or under charging, I always end up wasting my cells and purchasing new ones for my projects. I have tried charging these cells using 8V or 9V charger by joining two cells in series at once but to no avail. Instead, my cells are wasted. So suggest me how to use my cells to the maximum capacity and charging circuits?

Comment: Use proper chargers.

Comment: I have tried charging by joining two cells in series and using another batteries or charger of equivalent volts but no use.

Comment: You can't magic something up and hope it works. Improper charging destroys batteries.

Comment: Proper charger means that it's manual or datasheet is stating "can charge Li-Ion cells in such and such configurations" or equivalent.

Comment: Use the appropriate charger for each type of cell.  NiCd cells are ~1.4 volts fully charged, and won't survive being charged by the 3.7 volt lithium charger.

Comment: Re, "...joining two cells in series..." That is a _Bad Idea_ unless the cells all were _permanently_ attached to each other when they all were new.  Think about what might happen if one cell in a series string reaches full capacity while another cell is only half way there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the right charger for each chemistry of cell.Your Ni-Cd cell may take abuse for slightly longer time. But you definitely got to watch for that Li-Ion cells, its like a ticking bomb once it starts overcharging especially with higher capacity cells.

As for the Ni-Cd if you meant that you are using a 3.6V pack in series to charge on an 8V or 9V, you might get away with it for a while provided to don't leave it to overcharge and heat-up.

**Please get a proper charger at least for your own safety**. I've tried what you have done back when I was kid and yes I have ruined dozens of Ni-Cd cells. The encounter with my maiden charging(back then I had no internet access and I wasn't aware about this chemistry) with a 3.7V 700mAh Li-ion pack I had got from a MP3 player ended up causing an explosion and burning my carpet.